# postgresql enum Temporal

Tags: postgresql, temporal-database

i'm would like add value to the enum i use this query :

```
ALTER TYPE enum_missions_status ADD VALUE 'COMPLETED'
```

with my main table is sucess but when i try this query :

```
ALTER TYPE enum_historisationMissions_status ADD VALUE 'COMPLETED'
```

for my tempory table : https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SQL2011Temporal

i have this error message :

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeBaseError: type "enum_historisationmissions_status" does not exist
```

he modify my M to m.

whe i try :

```
 ALTER TYPE "enum_historisationMissions_status" ADD VALUE 'COMPLETED'
```

i have this error :

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeBaseError: type "enum_historisationmissions_status" does not exist
```

How do i add enum to temporal table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general SQL is case insensitive. Thus `enum_historisationMissions_status` and `enum_historisationmissions_status` denote the same object. To avoid this behaviour you can include the name in double quoutes, e.g. `"enum_historisationMissions_status"` names an object with lower and upper characters.

Comment: To add to this. The SQL standard states that unquoted identifiers fold to upper case. Because of readability and historical precedent, PostgreSQL folds to lower case. These two behaviors are functionally very similar. If you created an object in a different SQL compliant DB by quoting it: "MyTable" then referenced it by calling it MyTable would actually be referencing MYTABLE (or in pgsql mytable) and it won't match.

Generally either quote EVERYTHING or nothing and you won't have this problem in either db.